# Is the form element <input type="file"> dependent on external software to recognize filetypes to upload?

Tags: html, browser, xhtml, file-upload

I've been running into some unusual behavior in my upload form. It seems that the form won't recognize an office spreadsheet file unless office is installed on the client's machine. This doesn't make any sense to me but in Chrome, Firefox, and IE8 my upload fails to pass an XLSX file unless the client computer has Microsoft Office installed.

Is this normal? Is there a way around this?

Here's the basic form I'm using:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<%=request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")%>">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>XLS File </th>
                <td><input type="file" name="UploadXLS" value=""  style="width:300px" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p><button type="submit">Upload</button></p>
    </form>
```

### edit

Here is the code that validates an xls or xlsx file:

```
if  NOT (trim(fileXLS.ContentType) = "application/vnd.ms-excel" _
    or trim(fileXLS.ContentType) = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" ) _
then
    dictImportErrors.add "xlsContentType", "Spreadsheet file is not an XLS or an XLSX<br />Or, the file could be open in another location"
end if
```

`fileXLS` is an object comming from Persits.Upload dll in classic asp.

Comment: Impossible to answer without knowing which method you are using to validate/recognize the upload.

Comment: That's very weird. I'm pretty sure that is not normal behavior.

Comment: @quakkels where are you validating the file type or trying to recognize it as XSLX?

Comment: @quakkels yes, but using what method? If you use the MIME type sent by the browser, it's possible that this makes sense. But it's not a good thing to rely on that information anyway, as it's unreliable and can be tampered with

Comment: ooh... good point I'll look at the code.

Comment: @quakkels are you still working on the edit? I can't see it yet

Comment: yes working on edit ... done now though

Comment: @quakkels I added a paragraph to my answer

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "won't recognize" it? When you do a file upload, the client should just display a "select file" window and then send the selected file. The client shouldn't have to "recognize" anything other than the existence of the file. Do you mean that it's not showing up in the "select file" window? Or are you expecting the client to do something more than this?

Comment: @Jay he is polling the MIME type of the file that the browser sends along with the uploaded file. Apparently, if MS office is installed, the browser manages to detect the correct MIME type `application/vnd.ms-....` instead of just the generic `application/octet-stream`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how MIME type detection works on Windows systems, but if you are using the MIME type sent by the browser, I suppose this behaviour makes sense. I suppose MS Office will inform whatever part of the operating system resolves file types to MIME types that files with the extension .XSLX are to be treated as `application/ms-office-whatever`. Browsers will have their own MIME type table but will rely on the operating system for unknown types.

However, relying on that MIME type is not a good idea anyway. It can be unreliable (as we can see) and it can be tampered with.

It would be more feasible to do a proper server-side check. For example, AFAIK, XSLX files are zipped collections of XML files, no? In that case, you could unzip the file and take a peek inside.

**Re your edit:** This seems indeed to be relying on the MIME type sent. It would be better to do a detection on server side. I'm not familiar with ASP  though so I don't know what options for that exist. Chances are it is possible to detect a XLSX file without having to manually unzip it.

Comment: Yes, It looks like when I check the mimetype, Persits Upload is getting the mimetype returned by the browser. So I suspect that if the excel mimetype isn't registered on the clients system, then the browser would not send it correctly.

Comment: @quakkels: The browser is sending the file correctly, just not setting the mime-type properly. However, you should not rely on the mime-type sent by the client, as spoofing that is easy and could lead to *really bad things*.